# How to push jaCoCo test results to a Gitlab merge request with Jenkins without using Gitlab enterprise edition?

Tags: git, unit-testing, jenkins, gitlab, jacoco

Can you somehow put test results done by jaCoCo to a Gitlab merge request window? The Jenkins job builds and tests given gitlab repo and is triggered by a gitlab webhook on a given merge request.

For example, I imagine it that test coverage or at least the result whether tests passed or failed is going to be shown somewhere in here: [How I imagine it(gitlab merge request)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcMd6.png)

For now I just have option on that creates this kind of a pipeline result whether a job was built successfully or not, which doesn't tell me anything about the tests.

I know there is a way to do this thing with a JSON API response (Gitlab pages, runners and gitlab CI) and with some kind of a code coverage tool like a sonarQube, but the problem is I need gitlab enterprise edition for that, which I don't have currently, so I'm looking for a way to do this with a basic Gitlab.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way you can post specific results to a Merge Request in Gitlab Core/Free is to use the GitLab Notes API and submit a discussion item to the MR. It wouldn't be in the "Merge Request Widget", as they call it (the part you mentioned in the image), but the only way to get certain results in there is in the paid versions.

See this operation specifically: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/notes.html#create-new-merge-request-note